# Strange jQuery XML problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have a list of quotes in an XML document.  Each quote is wrapped like this:

```
<Item>
    <Quote>This is a quote!</Quote>
    <Source>-- this is the Source of the Quote!</Source>
</Item>
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
    var html = '';
    var tmpl = '<li class=""><p class="quote">__quote</p><p class="source">__source</p></li>';

    $(quoteObj).find('Item').each(function(){ 

        $that = $(this);

        var _quote = $that.children('Quote').text();
        var _source = $that.children('Source').text();

        var qhtml = tmpl.replace('__quote', _quote).replace('__source', _source);

        html += qhtml;

    });

   return html;
```

In the end product, the `QUOTES` are all there, but the `SOURCES` aren't.  I can't for the life of me figure out why.  What's right in front of me that I can't see?

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION TO ANSWER COMMENTS:

1. The XML is properly formed, and I changed it above.
2. I added the `var tmpl` line to show what I'm replacing in the loop.  The `__quote` is being replaced, and the `__source` is at least being acted upon, since the second `<p>` is empty, instead of containing a string.
3. I have checked the actual XML coming back from the AJAX call, and it is all there, as it should be.

It seems to me this is some sort of issue with scoping and `this`, or with the action of the `.children()` method, but I still can't find it.

ONE LAST NOTE:

Changed the XML tag case to Initial Caps, which it is in the document in question.

Comment: Could you post the actual XML? Your sample is not well-formed (which could be the answer to your question, or could just be a shortcut you took to show us something quickly)

Comment: do you the values in the xml for Source. it should be sraight forward check , just hit the break point in firebut ,you can easliy check that.

Comment: @hollenback , just more info , check if you are getting results from backend through .net panel if you are getting results then add a breakpoint in the loop and check the values.

Comment: What is tmpl, and what is replace() ? If replace should be the native string-replace, this expects a RegExp as first argument, not a string.

Comment: @Dr.Molle, if by "native" string-replace you mean javascript's, that first argument can be a regexp **or** a string.

Comment: @OP: when you say "the SOURCES aren't", do you mean the '__source' has been removed, or that they're untouched?

Comment: Edited the post to add more information.

Comment: @LarsH: shame on me, I think it's time to put my JS 1.3-reference to garbage can^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried this and the only thing I had to change was the `find` line to match the case of the XML node, eg

```
$(quoteObj).find('ITEM').each( function() {
```

I did also change the `$that` assignment line to include the `var` keyword, but it was working before I did that

```
var $that = $(this);
```

Comment: Were those the only change you made? Cos, it doesn't work with thos changes for me. Could you test it with the jQuery on google and see what result you get? Link to jQuery file from google : <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></SCRIPT>

Comment: That's exactly what I'm using

Comment: Super weird. Wonder why I can get it to work with your changes? Care to post the complete example?

Comment: Yes it works when loading data from external file, but It does not work if you take xml in a local variable and then try to parse it using jquery.

Comment: I'm not sure what the exact cause of the problem was - as a note, the case of the XML is Initial Caps, and it was correct in the JavaScript.  But by changing it from 'Source' to 'Byline' - it worked.  I have no idea if this is some sort of strange bug in jQuery, but at least this answer gave me a push in the right direction.  Thanks!

Comment: jQuery doesn't parse XML; passing a string to the `$()` function merely assigns it as the `innerHTML` property of an HTML element, which is not at all a reliable to parse XML. You need to use the browser's built-in XML parser. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery doesn't parse XML. Passing an XML string to `$()` simply assigns the string as the `innerHTML` property of an element, which has variable and unpredictable results. You need to parse the XML yourself, using the browser's built-in XML parser, and then pass the resulting document into jQuery:

```
var parseXml;

if (window.DOMParser) {
    parseXml = function(xmlStr) {
       return ( new window.DOMParser() ).parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml");
    };
} else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject != "undefined" && new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")) {
    parseXml = function(xmlStr) {
        var xmlDoc = new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async = "false";
        xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlStr);
        return xmlDoc;
    };
} else {
    parseXml = function() { return null; }
}


var xmlStr = "<Item><Quote>This is a quote!</Quote><Source>-- this is the Source of the Quote!</Source></Item>";

var xmlDoc = parseXml(xmlStr);
$xml = $(xmlDoc);

$xml.find('Item').each(function() {
    // Do stuff with each item here
    alert("Item");
});
```