# Read xml in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I have below string in javascript

```
var output = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><abc><xyz><xyzResponse><URL>http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fnet%2Fxyz.do%3Fpartner%3Ddummy%26id%3Dba0e245f-ae67-40b6-986d-3242acea4c04</URL><StatusMsg>SUCCESS</StatusMsg><ID>hello.com</ID><AID>test</AID></xyzResponse></xyz></abc>';
```

I want to parse this as xml and get values out of it.

I have tried below code

```
var xmlObj = $(output);
alert(xmlObj.find('URL').text())
```

It works in FireFox but does not work in IE. It does not give any error but does not show any content.

How to read xml that is string format and use content using javascript across the browsers?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `$()` function doesn't parse XML: it treats it as HTML and inserts it into the HTML DOM, which doesn't work in general. If you're using jQuery 1.5, you can use its new [`parseXML()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) method:

```
var xmlObj = $.parseXML(output);
alert( $(xmlObj).find('URL').text() );
```

If you can't use jQuery 1.5, you'll need an XML parsing function such as the one I posted here: [Strange jQuery XML problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111881/strange-jquery-xml-problem/4173689#4173689)

Comment: Only one update for jQuery 1.5, as per docs it should be $($.parseXML(output))

Comment: @Jaydeep: Oh yes, you're absolutely right. Careless mistake, now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following for parsing xml for all browsers. I hope you will find it helpful too.

```
if(window.DOMParser)//Firefox, Chrome and others Browsers
    {
        var xmlString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(response);
        parser=new DOMParser();
        xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(xmlString,"text/xml");
    }
    else // Internet Explorer
    {
        xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async="false";
        xmlDoc.load(response);
    }
```